# How to create new console in separate view

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have created a new console using following code.

```
this.console = new IOConsole(name, null);
IConsole[] consoles = new IConsole[1];
consoles[0] = this.console ;
ConsolePlugin.getDefault().getConsoleManager()
                .addConsoles(consoles);
IOConsoleOutputStream consoleStream = this.console.newOutputStream();
consoleStream.write("Printing in console..");
```

I have created 3 new consoles same as above.

But actually I don't want to add one of my new consoles page to existing consoles.
I want to create new console view, that should display these console messages.
How can I get separate console view rather to add existing console manager.
Because I want to detach one of my own console views, not other consoles.

Is it possible to create new view and attach one console to that view.
Could any one help me to get this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struggled with this problem for last two days. Anyhow found solution for that on my own.
Still some issues are there.

I want to share what I got.

I just created new view.That view class should implement *IConsoleView* (of course, extends *IViewPart* ).

In *createPatrControl()*, I have added following code.

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
  IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow()
    .getActivePage();
  IViewReference ref = page.findViewReference(IConsoleConstants.ID_CONSOLE_VIEW);
  IOConsole  console = createConsole(); // here create new console

  // this will ad console page to corresponding view                
        IPageBookViewPage pageBook = targetConsole.createPage(this);
        try {
            pageBook.init(new PageSite((IViewSite) ref.getView(true).getSite()));
        } catch (PartInitException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pageBook.createControl(parent);

}
```

But I think,Something has missed here.

Actually, I want this to be done outside of that view class.
After creation of the console, programatically I want to create new view and add like as below,

```
// here that new view should be get and passed into createPage()
PageBookViewPage pageBook = targetConsole.createPage(IConsoleView);
```